# Webscrapping a page can't find text content regardless of lowercase or uppercase

Tags: python, web-scraping, findall

I've been trying to webscrap a page, but when I want to filter the information regardless of a 100% match (uppercase, lowercase, etc) I can't get it to work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://www.pemex.com/procura/procedimientos-de-contratacion/concursosabiertos/Paginas/Pemex-Transformación-Industrial.aspx"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4")


texto_licitacion = results.find_all("td", string=lambda text: "Bienes" in text.lower())
```

And I get these results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\acast\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2030, in find_all
    return self._find_all(name, attrs, string, limit, generator,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\acast\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 841, in _find_all
    found = strainer.search(i)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\acast\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2320, in search
    found = self.search_tag(markup)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\acast\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2291, in search_tag
    if found and self.string and not self._matches(found.string, self.string):
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\acast\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2352, in _matches
    return match_against(markup)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I already tried in another webpage and it worked correctly, but in this one I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the elements have no text, so `text` is `None`. Check for that in your filter.

You also need to check for `bienes`, since `text.lower()` can't have an uppercase `B`.

```
texto_licitacion = results.find_all("td", string=lambda text: text and "bienes" in text.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda function will always return `False` as a value since the phrase you're looking for, "Bienes", has a capital letter "B". Because of this, the `string` keyword argument you want to pass into the `find_all()` function isn't passing a string but instead a boolean value (which in this case will always be `False`.

If you want to find all the `<td>` elements that contain the word "bienes" (lowercase), the correct function call would be:

```
def bienes_in_tag(tag):
    return 'bienes' in tag.lower()


texto_licitacion = results.find_all("td", bienes_in_tag)
for tag in texto_licitacion:
    print(tag)
```

Here, I defined a function that returns a boolean. BeautifulSoup [lets you use these functions](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to look for all the  tags which have the phrase 'bienes' in them.